# Bash - Script that reads .txt file and stores the info in variables to be used later

Tags: bash, shell, unix, network-programming, network-interface

I'm working on a bash script that must be able to create "network interface profile configurations", store them in any kind of file (.txt I guess) and then, if called with parameters, eg: ./myscript eth0 myprofile

must execute the commands in myprofile.txt to configure that network interface.

So, right now, I am trying to put this info in a .txt file (ip, netmask, gateway and proxy): Example of format (data might not be valid, of course!)

192.168.20.3 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.1 20.139.30.4:80

As you can see, I got this info separated by "whitespaces". I want to know if this is a "bad practice", because I want the script to, given a filename, retrieve this information and store it separately in variables so I can call commands like "ifconfig, route, etc". with this info.

Any ideas of how could I accomplish this?

Comment: I would also include the profile-name next to each 4-item config from the txt, so that when myscript is called with `myprofile` parameter, it could find the associated configuration in the txt "database". Using whitespace is certainly not an issue, unless a whitespace character can appear in the name of (ip, netmask, gateway and proxy).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, chatraed. Actually, I have total freedom to achieve this functionality in any way possible. I can store each profile in a separated .txt file if I want to (which could be easier, I guess). Any suggestions from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how would I handle the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Usage is ./$0 eth-name profile-name"
    exit 1
fi

eth=$1
profile=$2

if [[ ! -f "$profile.txt" ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: $profile.txt file not found!"
    exit 1
fi

# TODO: validate $eth

ip=$(awk '{print $1}' "$profile.txt")
netmask=$(awk '{print $2}' "$profile.txt")
gateway=$(awk '{print $3}' "$profile.txt")
proxy=$(awk '{print $4}' "$profile.txt")

echo "ip: $ip"
echo "netmask: $netmask"
echo "gateway: $gateway"
echo "proxy: $proxy"

# DO whatever with $ip, $netmask, $gateway, $proxy
```

By running the example, I get this:

```
$ > cat myprofile.txt
192.168.20.3 255.255.255.0 192.168.20.1 20.139.30.4:80
$ > bash myscript.sh eth0 myprofile
ip: 192.168.20.3
netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 192.168.20.1
proxy: 20.139.30.4:80
$ >
```

Comment: You sir are ABSOLUTELY MY HERO. I really need to learn more about bash scripting. You saved my life! Thank you very much.